# "Warning: Attempt to present... on... whose view is not..." issue when presenting from a childVC --

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller

In short, I'm presenting a view from a childVC that's just been added to the view hierarchy, but apparently it hasn't been added to the window hierarchy yet.

I've just started this project and set it up as a page-based project. The boiler for the `UIPageViewController` that was added to the included `RootViewController` is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

    let startingViewController: CameraViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })

    self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view) // !! -- viewDidAppear for CameraViewController called here

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 40.0, 40.0)
    }
    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect

    self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    // Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers
}
```

The only line I changed was setting my own VC as the `startingViewController`:

```
 let startingViewController: CameraViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
```

I'm trying to have the first screen be a camera - an ImagePickerVC. Here is my code for that. As you can see, I am adding a `UIImageView` to this `CamerViewController` to show the preview, but am trying to first present the `UIImagePickerController` on `viewDidAppear`:

```
import UIKit

class CameraViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func didTapCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        presentImagePicker();

    }

    var dataObject: AnyObject?

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.        
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);

        presentImagePicker();
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func presentImagePicker() {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in

            println("save bolean")
        })
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }



}
```

However, I'm getting a warning and the `imagePicker` is never presented:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x14e833a00> on <Here.CameraViewController: 0x14e614af0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I've set breakpoints and found that `viewDidAppear` for the `CameraViewController` is called on this line when adding the `PageViewController` to the `RootViewController`:

```
 self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view) // !! -- viewDidAppear for CameraViewController called here
```

This seems as it should be but why the error? The view just got added so it's in the RootViewController's view hierarchy.

---

I also added a button to present the `UIImagePickerController` manually from the `CameraViewController`. This presents it find without any problem.

Comment: You have to add the subviews in `viewWillAppear` `viewDidLoad` is too early

Comment: I had a similar problem the other day when using UIImagePickerController....try this _imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext before presenting.